# Opinions on and Experiences with Excel 2010's Evolutionary Solver method

Tags: excel, vba, solver

Microsoft has augmented the existing Simplex (Linear) and Gradient (Non-linear) solver engines of the standard Solver Add-In by an Evolutionary solver engine aiming at non-smooth discontinuous problems where global optimal solutions are generally hard (or most of the time even impossible) to find with the other engines. In fact, it is one of the solvers that was previously only available through Frontline's Premium Solver product line, so I think it can be considered a generous addition to the standard solver that ships with Excel.

I haven't heard a lot about people using this new engine and guess that most solver users haven't noticed this recent addition by Microsoft. I become aware of it here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/what-s-new-in-excel-2010-HA010369709.aspx

I would therefore like to hear about your opinions and experiences with it, also with respect to reasonable settings as it seems to take a lot more time to converge than the other methods.

Comment: Good question, but I don't think it belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: i do use the solver as part of my vba programming - so where would you suggest to ask that question?

Comment: I recommended superuser.com when I voted to close, but programmers.stackexchange.com might be good as well. Generally if a question doesn't include or relate directly to code, it doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: @Steve, This is more of a general discussion topic, and stackoverflow is for specific questions. If there were a specific "how can I?" or "does this work this way?" way to frame it, there's nothing wrong with asking about the Excel solver. The formulas that your model is using and the way they interact with the solver process are "code" enough, but you need a specific question.

Comment: got it! I'll do the following: I'll copy my question to another forum and then delete the it since it is inappropriate here.

Comment: how nice, your suggestion of posting my quesiton on programmers.stackexchange.com just resulted in it being closed: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/68969/opinions-on-and-experiences-with-excel-2010s-evolutionary-solver-method

Comment: That's annoying. As aksed, I'm not sure it's right for superuser either. Excel is tricky, since some people on stackoverflow are eager to declare formulas "not programming related". But you do need a specific question on any of these sites, rather than an open-ended discussion topic. You might try marking your question "community wiki" and rephrasing it as something more question-like...maybe "What are some reasonable settings to make Excel 2010's evolutionary solver converge [given this particular model]?" I personally would consider that fine, although some will still want it migrated to su.

Answer (score -1):

I've used Evolutionary solver engine developing a MPS (master production schedule) trying to involve most aspects and get an optimal solution, I've found this:

Sometimes it gives the optimal solution, but sometimes you have to give it some kind of hints, such as moving some variables, as will, and see what happens, therefore, I wouldn't recommend it for final decisions, but give it a chance!

Comment: by the way sorry if I wrote badly English isn't my native language :D